# MVP for android. Is it worth the effort?

Tags: android, design-patterns, mvp

Recently I stumbled upon a few articles on using the MVP pattern for developing android applications.

I would like to know:

> 1. whether it is worth the effort to move towards a MVP pattern, given
>      that fact the android framework is not inherently designed keeping
>      MVP in mind whereas iOS development using Swift enforces the MVP
>      pattern (if I am right).
> 2. Is the development time impacted a lot on using MVP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your points:

1. MVP is worth the move in the long run - for a new project definitely start using MVP. For an existing codebase, it will be time consuming to untangle the logic in Activities, Fragments etc.
2. In the short term dev time is impacted as you'll have to learn MVP etc. In the long run, you'll save time bug fixing etc.

Here's a great article on [MVP and Android](http://antonioleiva.com/mvp-android/)